# почему форма всегда валидна?

Tags: javascript, валидация, backbone.js

Помогите пожалуйста понять почему форма получается всегда валидной

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/udXL5/629/

Я использую плагин backbone-validation и бутстраповские модальные окна. В модели прописываю такие правила валидации:

```
APP.DiaryModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

  defaults: {
    title: undefined,
    desc: undefined
  },

  validation: {  
    title: [ 
              { required: true, msg: 'Поле не может быть пустым' },
              { minLength: 3,   msg: 'Введите не менее 3 символов' }
            ],    

    desc: [ 
              { maxLength: 200,   msg: 'Введите не более 200 символов' }
            ]                                                                                             
  }       

});
```

После того как я пытаюсь сабмитить форму с пустым полем #diaryTitle, я получаю в консоли следующее:

> is v true true true (index):164 valid   r {cid: "c3", attributes:
>   Object, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object, changed:
>   Object…}

То есть получается так что форма валидна(!). А в реальности она не валидна. потому что поле #diaryTitle пустое

Код, отвечающий за валидацию в APP.DiariesView:

```
events:{
    'click #showAddDiaryModal' : 'showAddDiaryModal',
    'click #addDiaryBtn' : 'addDiary'
  }, 

  addDiary: function() { 
    var titleValue =  $.trim(this.$el.find('#diaryTitle').val()), 
        descValue =   $.trim(this.$el.find('#diaryDesc').val());

    var model = new APP.DiaryModel();

    model.set({
      title: titleValue,
      desc: descValue
    });  

    console.log('is v', model.isValid(), model.isValid('title'), model.isValid('desc'))

    if(model.isValid()) { 
      console.log('valid', titleValue, descValue, model)
    } else {
      console.log('invalid')
    };

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю что для валидации используется этот [плагин](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation)

Тогда для валидации моделей нужно примешать (добавить mixin) класс валидации в модель объекта.
Его можно добавить в прототип `Backbone.Model`, если валидация нужна во всех моделях. Либо в прототип `APP.DiaryModel`, если валидация нужна только в этой модели.

Пример:

Для всех моделей:

```
_.extend(Backbone.Model.prototype, Backbone.Validation.mixin);
```

Только для `APP.DiaryModel`:

```
_.extend(APP.DiaryModel.prototype, Backbone.Validation.mixin);
```